# Why do images flicker if the image width and height are not specified?

Tags: html

According to

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

> Always specify the width and height of an image. If width and height are not specified, the page will flicker while the image loads.

Personally I have tried testing it and never noticed it happening. Anyone seen it before and know why it happens?

Comment: FIrst mistake "according to w3schools"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

w3schools is not known for their accurate information, and historically was so bad that http://w3fools.com was created to explain just how bad the information was.

The "flicker" that w3schools is referring to is probably the content shifting that happens when an image changes sizes after it loads. Browsers have generally optimized this shifting to mostly go away, but it can still occur depending on how images are loaded and styles are handled.

The main point being to use `[width]` and `[height]` attributes to inform the browser of what size the content is expected to be to make correct rendering as fast as possible.